# Advanced merge directory tree with cp in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, shell-script, file-transfer, bash-scripting

I need to:

1. Copy all of a tree's folders (with all files, including hidden) under `/sourcefolder/*` preserving user privileges to `/destfolder/`
2. If there is a conflict with a file (a file with the same name exists in `destfolder`), then

   - rename file in destfolder with a standard rule, like add "old" prefix to filename (readme.txt will become oldreadme.txt)
   - copy the conflicted file from source to destination

Conflicts between folders should be transparent - if same directory exists in both sourcefolder and destfolder, then preserve it and recursively copy its content according to the above rules.

I need also a .txt report that describes all files/folders added to destfolder and files that were renamed.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

rsync is probably what you want.

Try something like this as root:

> rsync --backup --suffix=old --verbose --archive /sourcefolder/ /destfolder/

See "man rsync" for details of the options.

The output will (hopefully) be suitable for your text report. So run the command with this on the end:

> > report.txt

Comment: Yep, pretty much this.